# "TypeError: can't pickle CVM objects" while using PyMC3

Tags: python, pymc3

I have tried using PyMC3 with various different models, but keep getting the same error : "TypeError: can't pickle CVM objects".

This is the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-4-4b462b460b57>", line 3, in <module>
trace = pm.sample(500)

File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymc3/sampling.py", line 442, in sample
trace = _mp_sample(**sample_args)

File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymc3/sampling.py", line 982, in _mp_sample
traces = Parallel(n_jobs=cores, mmap_mode=None)(jobs)

File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 962, in __call__
self.retrieve()

File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 865, in retrieve
self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))

File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 515, in wrap_future_result
return future.result(timeout=timeout)

File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/_base.py", line 431, in result
return self.__get_result()

File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/_base.py", line 382, in __get_result
raise self._exception

TypeError: can't pickle CVM objects
```

I have tried looking for solutions to this error, but haven't found one yet. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Installing from the master branch appears to solve the problem : pip3 install -U git+https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3.git

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: I encountered the same problem, and though what you posted as an answer is not what solved it, it led me down the path to figuring the error out. Attempting to reinstall pymc3, using your code, threw up an error to me that anaconda demanded some different version of `python-dateutil` than pymc3 wanted. 

So I updated my anaconda distribution, updated pymc3 again, found another package that didn't want `python-dateutil` updated, uninstalled that, updated `python-dateutil`, re-ran your code, and now the error is gone :D.

Comment: Hmm... I didn’t face a problem with python-dateutil. Thanks for your comment though! This will surely be helpful for someone with a similar problem.

Comment: having the same problem here and the suggested solution doesnt work. Any other ideas?

Comment: You may not have installed the package into the right directory. Try specifying the complete location of the pip during installation. Do uninstall your current package before you install the next one.

Comment: If you use Anaconda you can just do `conda install -c conda-forge pymc3` to get the later version.

Comment: @dain, I did try that. But I ended up getting the above mentioned error. It may have been updated recently, but I'm not exactly sure about that.